# Usage of instanceof in a generic method

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

I started to learn generics today, but this is somelike weird for me:

I have a generic method:

```
  public<T> HashMap<String, T> getAllEntitySameType(T type) {

        System.out.println(type.getClass());
        HashMap<String, T> result = null;

        if(type instanceof Project)
        {
            System.out.println(type.toString());
            System.out.println("Yes, instance of Project;");
        }

        if(type instanceof String)
        {
            System.out.println(type.toString());
            System.out.println("Yes, instance of String;");
        }
        this.getProjects();
        return result;
    }
```

And i can easily determinate the class of the T type

```
    Project<Double> project = new Project<Double>();
    company2.getAllEntitySameType(project);
    company2.getAllEntitySameType("TestString");
```

The output will be:

```
class Project
Yes, instance of Project;
class java.lang.String
TestString
Yes, instance of String;
```

I thought in generics we can't use instance of. Something is not complete in my knowledge. Thanks...

Comment: You can't do `type instanceof T` ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That should be an answer, IMO, because that's the core of the OP's confusion.

Comment: so as it seems, i can not use exactly the opposite of what i've used?

Comment: You can do `System.out.println(type);` so you don't even know if it is `null` or not.

Comment: thanks, i can really use everything. So the thing is i can determine the arguments and i can't determine the parameters... Thanks!

Wold you mind doing an answer? and i can accept it! Thanks!

Comment: Peter's already answered the question above. On a side note, IMHO, if you are having to do "instanceof" in generic methods, you beat the point of writing generic methods in the first place.

Comment: Maybe you have right aishwarya, but my task is no to find all entity based on the argument and give back all from the same object... So in company it should be projects or workers, and i have no better idea...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` to check the *raw type* of an object, for example `Project`:

```
if (type instanceof Project)
```

Or with proper generics syntax for a `Project` of some unknown type:

```
if (type instanceof Project<?>)
```

But you can't [reify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29) a parameterized type like `Project<Double>` with `instanceof`, due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

```
if (type instanceof Project<Double>) //compile error
```

As Peter Lawrey [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219759/usage-of-instanceof-in-a-generic-method#comment19722898_14219759), you also can't check against type variables:

```
if (type instanceof T) //compile error
```

Comment: Anyway i make a mistake, because Project is a parameterized type --->
Project<Double> ... So now?:)

Comment: @czupe Edited to address that.

Comment: Thanks, now easier to understand. Voted up!