# Is using 'instanceOf' necessary when using generics?

Tags: java

I am having trouble figuring out how to write my equals method using generics as I am sure if using instanceOf is necessary. Im trying to compare that two ItemPairs are the same (logically equivalent) if both items within the pair are the same (logically equivalent)

Here is my attempt at it:

```
public class ItemPair<T> { 

private T item1; 
private T item2; 

public ItemPair(T item1, T item2) { 
    this.item1 = item1; 
    this.item2 = item2;
}

public T getItem1() {
    return item1;
}

public void setItem1(T item1) {
    this.item1 = item1; 
}

public T getItem2() {
    return item2;
}

public void setItem2(T item2) {
    this.item2 = item2; 
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof T) {
        return this.item1.equals(this.item2);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219759/usage-of-instanceof-in-a-generic-method) it may help.

Comment: What you're trying to do is impossible and completely wrong. `equals()` should be comparing `this` to `obj`, which is usually another `ItemPair`, not `item1` to `item2`.

Comment: Thank you for the link and suggestion!

Comment: If you're writing the equals method for class ItemPair, the instanceof should be for checking that class, not for T. Look at this class, it may be useful in your case: https://github.com/unicesi/amelia/blob/master/maven/org.amelia.dsl.lib/src/main/java/org/amelia/dsl/lib/util/Pair.java

Comment: You can use `if (! getClass().isInstance(obj)) {return false;} ItemPair<T> other = getClass().cast(obj);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `equals` method should not determine if the first item is equal to the second item of the same `ItemPair` object. It should determine if two `ItemPair`s are equal to each other:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof ItemPair))
        return false;
    IterPair other = (IterPair) obj;
    return this.item1.equals(other.item1) && this.item2.equals(other.item2);
}
```

Some additional conditions may be required for the cases where either of the items are null.

Comment: `if (obj == null)` is redundant. `instanceof` will anyway return false.

Comment: And if you don't want to have subclasses count as equal via instanceof, then you can compare `#getClass` (which is where the null check _would_ be necessary)

Comment: While the `(obj == null)` is redundant, there is a good chance that the JIT compiler will optimize it away.

Comment: Is `if (!(obj instanceof ItemPair))` could not be `if (!(obj instanceof ItemPair<?>))` to  avoid warning ? Here you use a raw `ItemPair`.

Comment: `return this.item1.equals(other.item1) && this.item2.equals(other.item2);` ==> `return Objects.equals(this.item1, other.item1) && Objects.equals(this.item2, other.item2);` to handle the null case.